Why Does Interchanging the quantities of elements in a data set result in the same standard deviation?
I'm trying to understand the behavior of standard deviation in a specific scenario. Consider two sets of data where the quantities of 20's and 40's are interchanged:
$A=\{20,20,20,20,40,40\}$
$B=\{40,40,40,40,20,20\}$
Despite the means being different, the standard deviation for both sets remains the same. In specific, why is the standard deviation symmetric if you have a 20s and b 40s versus when you have b 20s and a 40s? Would appreciate an intuitive answer to this symmetric property.

The word flipping is referring to a reflection on the number line.
First of all, if we have a random variable $X$, is it intuitive to accept that $-X$ has the same variance as $X$?
The negation here serves as a reflection about the point $0$. Every realization will be reflected to the opposite sign, and the expected value. Even the expected value changed the sign, the average squared distance to the expected value does not change during reflection.
Next, shifting by a deterministic constant will not change the variance - $X$ should have the same variance as $X + a$ where $a$ is a deterministic constant. This one should be more intuitive.
If you accept both, then in your example, if the original random variable $X$, the transformed random variable will be $30 \times 2 - X = 60 - X$. It is just a reflection about the point $30$ so the variance should be intuitively preserved after the transformation.
